# Reading a grayscale image in python shows 3 color channels instead of one

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am reading an image in python from a dataset which contains grayscale .png images.

img_1.png is already a grayscale image.

```
img=cv2.imread('img_1.png')
print(img.shape)
```

on reading the image, img.shape shows 3 channels.

```
(16, 16, 3)
```

However it is a grayscale image so it should have only width and height.

```
(16, 16)
```

I have also read the same grayscale image in MATLAB, it is only showing width and height.

but reading an rgb image in python and converting it to the grayscale does not show 3 channels. why it is so?

```
gray_img=cv2.imread('rgb_1.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(gray_img.shape)
```

output:

```
(1050, 1400)
```

Is the output of reading a grayscale image and an image converted to grayscale in python is same? what is the difference?

i want to read that grayscale image without showing channels.

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and perhaps review [ask].

Comment: Would you share a link with the image? For greyscale images, matplotlib should indeed return a (width, height) array without a channel dim according to [the doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html). Without the image, we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

`cv.imread` always converts everything to BGR, unless you tell it not to. use the `cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag to do that.

You mistake the number of dimensions for the size of the color dimension.

`(h,w)` is 2-dimensional, and it's equivalent to `(h,w,1)`, where the color dimension has size 1.

`(h,w,3)` is 3-dimensions (tuple has length 3), and the `3` in the last place says the color dimension has length 3 (for three colors).

Comment: If cv.imread always converts everything to BGR then what data does these 3-dimension contain? Does it replicate the values? how does it represent the values of a grayscale image if read with cv.imread without using the flag?

Comment: grayscale to BGR mapping usually just replicates the gray plane into the three color planes, which makes the color picture appear gray. just try it and look at the array you get.